# Binding a property that could be of multiple data types in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, templatebinding, computed-observable

So I have a custom knockout binding for handling time durations. I have an issue where a value in one of my forms *might* be a duration, but could also be a string or other value. The issue arises from the fact that duration values are represented as objects with two properties, duration and time_unit (which is itself an object with 2 properties. I have the various bound nodes tied up inside if bindings.

```
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {

    var allBindings = ko.toJS(allBindingsAccessor() || {}),
        source = allBindings.source || [],
        observable = valueAccessor(),
        value = ko.toJS(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(observable)),

        duration = new DurationControl({
            inputNode: inputNode,
            source: source,
            defaultValue: value
        });

    //attach duration control to element and render here

    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(inputNode.getDOMNode(), 'blur', function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();

        if (!observable.viewModelUpdating) {
            observable.viewModelUpdating = ko.observable(false);
        }

        if (duration.isValueValid(true)) {
            observable.viewModelUpdating(true);
            observable.duration(duration.getDuration());
            observable.time_unit.value(duration.getTimeUnit());
            observable.time_unit.id(sourceIdValueMap[duration.getTimeUnit()] || 0);
            observable.viewModelUpdating(false);
        }
    });
}
```

And my bound html

```
<!-- ko if: type() == 'string' -->
<div class="control wide">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: value" />
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: type() == 'duration' -->
<div class="control">
   <input type="text" data-bind="duration: value, source: metadata.time_units" />
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

If i do the initial binding with value being the correct object format like so

```
...,
value: {
    duration: '',
    time_unit: {
        value: '',
        id: '',
    }
},
...
```

everything works great. But if i start with value in some other format, like `..., value: 'nada', ...` it breaks trying to access observable.duration (and observable.time_unit.*).

When I evaluate value with the proper set up, i Get the object described above back out. If i try manually adding the duration/time_unit properties as observables, i still just get the empty string back out.

How do I best go about updating the viewmodel/bindings/etc *from inside my init function* so that it behaves as if the model was initially in that state when I initialized it?

Comment: In the view, you seem to have a type() observable that knows if the value is a duration or a string. Can't you use that in the customBinding and do different stuff if type() == 'string' ?

Comment: I could yes, and that is part of my backup plan. If i have to, I can have multiple value type observables (durationValue, stringValue, dateValue etc) and have value be a computed that grabs the appropriate one based on type, but if I can figure this problem out I can avoid duplicating all of that code (perhaps slightly modified) in a number of places and just have it handled by the bindings, simply binding to the value observable.

Comment: What would be the code you are trying to not duplicate?

Comment: This custom binding gets used in many different places/view models. Already I have 2 places where this is an issue. Using the workaround for this vm,  I'd have to do a switch on type and return the appropriate bound value, but it would be different for each vm. Being able to work around this would allow me to simply bind to the vm and bypass the computed logic in each vm.

Comment: But even if you detect the type of the viewModel, wouldn't you have to have a switch in the customBinding to do different things according to the type? Sorry if I don't understand the problem properly, it's a little late here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom binding is not the solution to your problem. Knockout will bind everything it encounters in the DOM therefore whichever type of object you initialise your value with, the other one will fail.  I've implemented something similar where an observable in my view-model stores multiple 'types' of object, which you will need 'type-specific' portions of UI bound to each.  This is how i tackled the problem:

Remove all instances of, `if: type() == '<type>'` and implement each piece of HTML as a [template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).

Now refactor that decision making process.  Use a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to decide which template is shown based on the `type()`.  Something like this...

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;

    self.type = ko.observable();
    self.value = ko.observable();

    self.currentValueTemplate = ko.computed(function(){
       switch(self.type()) {
           case 'string':
               return 'stringTemplate';

           case 'duration':
               return 'durationTemplate';

           default:
               throw 'invalid type';
       }
    });
```

Now simply add a template placeholder...

```
<!-- ko template: { name: currentValueTemplate, data: value } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

You may want to adapt this to fit the specifics of your application, but it is a tidier approach and will scale much better should you want to store an increasing variety of object types.